# add a button sapui5 javascript

Tags: javascript, sapui5, bsp

New to sapui5, and I'm trying to make a change to an existing development and add another button to this UI.

Here is my coding, I am trying to add oAssetBtn2 to the UI, the other button already works??

Currently, I am getting the error:
AppController.js:2283 Custom code error: Error: adding element with duplicate id 'assetBtn-Custom2'
Error: Error: adding element with duplicate id 'assetBtn-Custom2'

```
       ASSETCREATE = function() {
       var oAssetBtn2  = sap.ui.getCore().byId('assetBtn-Custom2');
       };

      ASSETCREATE.prototype.CUSTOM_POST_EXIT = function(methodName, view, 
      controller,methodSignature, dialog) {
        if (view == 'accountLineDetails') {
           sap.ui.getCore().byId('CategoryListDetAS').setProperty('enabled',false);
       this.accounting = 
       sap.ui.getCore().byId("accAssignment").getController().accounting;
       var oFormModel = this.accounting.callMethod("_getFormModel");
       var oModel = oFormModel.oData ;
    jQuery.sap.require("sap.ui.commons.MessageBox");
    var oBtnLayout  = 
    sap.ui.getCore().byId(sap.ui.getCore().byId('saveBtn').getParent().getId());
    var oAssetBtn   = sap.ui.getCore().byId('assetBtn-Custom');
    // Add the "Create Multiple Asset" button in the footer layout
    jQuery.sap.require("sap.ui.commons.MessageBox");
    var oBtnLayout2 = 
  sap.ui.getCore().byId(sap.ui.getCore().byId('cancelBtn').getParent().getId());
    var oAssetBtn2  = sap.ui.getCore().byId('assetBtn-Custom2');
        <%
        data: lv_langu type sy-langu.
  lv_langu = sy-langu.
%>
    var lv_language = "" ;
    var lv_text = "";
    var lv_multiple_txt = "";
    if( lv_language == "F" ){
       lv_text = "Créer Immo";
       lv_multiple_txt = "Créer Plusieurs Actifs";
      }
      else{
       lv_text = "Create Asset";
       lv_multiple_txt = "Create Multiple Assets";
      }
        var oAssetBtn2 = new sap.ui.commons.Button({
        id   : "assetBtn-Custom2",
        text : lv_multiple_txt,
        tooltip : Appcc.getText("Create many Assets")
        });
    if (!oAssetBtn) {
        var oAssetBtn = new sap.ui.commons.Button({
        id   : "assetBtn-Custom",
        text : lv_text,
        tooltip : Appcc.getText("Creates an Asset")
      });
```

thanks fellow coders!

View of the error in Chrome:
[err](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qrsiG.jpg)

Comment: Hi Everyone,I found the issue I was missing the statement to add the button to the UI oBtnLayout2.addContent(oAssetBtn2); I added that and the button is now on the screen.... YAH!!

Answer (score 1):

For adding a button to your app, you must bind it to your view or viewing page. How are you going to do this `[Layout/view name].addContent([button name]);`
in your case it will be 
`oBtnLayout2.addContent(oAssetBtn2);`